# crystal report formula get sum depend on payment mood

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

i'v crystal report have two types of payment mood 
1's is Cash 
2's is Visa
how get sum of each payment mood in report footer ?

```
ACT P.Mood Amount
987 Cash   300
988 Cash   200
989 Visa   200
252 Cash   210 
253 Visa   310
475 Cash   108
522 Visa   404
```

i wanna get Sum For cash and for Visa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `P.Mood` and take the sum of **cash** and **visa** in group footer and report footer.

Answer (score 0):

Option I:

- Add a cross-tab object to the `report footer` section.  \
- Place the mood in the rows and the amount in the summarized fields sections, respectively.

Option II:

- Create a formula field:

```
//{@cash}
IF {P.mood}="Cash" Then {P.amount}
```

- Create a second formula field:

```
  //{@visa}
  IF {P.mood}="Visa" Then {P.amount}
```

- Insert a summary field on each formula in the `report footer` section

Answer (score 0):

Create two formula fields(intializer,Sum) and place initializer in header section and Sum in details section.

place following code in Initializer FF

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar dSum:=0;
```

Place following code in Sum FF

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar dSum;
if (P.Mood} = "Cash" Then
     dSum:=dSum+(P.Amount};
```

Create another field SumofCash and place following code in it.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar dSum;
dSum;
```

now place this field in Footer Section.

**NOTE**: Sum field in Detail section and  Initializer in Header section will be suppressed.